# Java multiple file transfer over socket

Tags: java

Ok, trying to transfer a specified directory of files over a socket, remove the directory objects from the arraylist, so only files are left, and transfer them 1 by 1 over the same socket.  The arraylist here is filled with ONLY files, no directories.  Heres the receive and send code for the client and server respectively .  The code runs fine without errors, except for ALL the data is being written to the first file.  The subsequent files are created in the server folder, but they are 0 bytes.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

THIS IS THE SERVER CODE FOR RECEIVING THE FILES

```
public void receive(){


    try {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
//read the number of files from the client
        int number = dis.readInt();
        ArrayList<File>files = new ArrayList<File>(number);
        System.out.println("Number of Files to be received: " +number);
        //read file names, add files to arraylist
        for(int i = 0; i< number;i++){
            File file = new File(dis.readUTF());
            files.add(file);
        }
        int n = 0;
        byte[]buf = new byte[4092];

        //outer loop, executes one for each file
        for(int i = 0; i < files.size();i++){

            System.out.println("Receiving file: " + files.get(i).getName());
            //create a new fileoutputstream for each new file
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\users\\tom5\\desktop\\salestools\\" +files.get(i).getName());
            //read file
            while((n = dis.read(buf)) != -1){
                fos.write(buf,0,n);
                fos.flush();
            }
            fos.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

THIS IS THE CLIENT CODE FOR SENDING THE FILES

```
public void send(ArrayList<File>files){

    try {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println(files.size());
//write the number of files to the server
        dos.writeInt(files.size());
        dos.flush();

        //write file names 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < files.size();i++){
            dos.writeUTF(files.get(i).getName());
            dos.flush();
        }

        //buffer for file writing, to declare inside or outside loop?
        int n = 0;
        byte[]buf = new byte[4092];
        //outer loop, executes one for each file
        for(int i =0; i < files.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(files.get(i).getName());
            //create new fileinputstream for each file
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));

            //write file to dos
            while((n =fis.read(buf)) != -1){
                dos.write(buf,0,n);
                dos.flush();

            }
            //should i close the dataoutputstream here and make a new one each time?
        }
        //or is this good?
        dos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Trying to teach myself Java, just doing some simple projects to play with io for the first time.  I have a feeling my dos.write(buf,0,n) and its receive partner just keep reading and writing thus all data being written to the first file? Do i need to add a control to signal when the first file has been written completely?

Comment: Hmm, still having the same problem, all data is being written to the first file dunno what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: another option would be to write the sizes of each file, along with the file names, in the 'header'. Then your server-side code can know when to stop writing to each file, and start the next.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are reading the socket until `read()` returns -1. This is the end-of-stream condition (EOS). EOS happens when the peer closes the connection. Not when it finishes writing one file.

You need to send the file size ahead of each file. You're already doing a similar thing with the file count. Then make sure you read exactly that many bytes for that file:

```
String filename = dis.readUTF();
long fileSize = dis.readLong();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
while (fileSize > 0 && (n = dis.read(buf, 0, (int)Math.min(buf.length, fileSize))) != -1)
{
  fos.write(buf,0,n);
  fileSize -= n;
}
fos.close();
```

You can enclose all this in a loop that terminates when `readUTF()` throws `EOFException`. Conversely of course you have to call `writeUTF(filename)` and `writeLong(filesize)` at the sender, before sending the data.

Comment: Can't the `shutdownOutput` also be used to indicate `EOF`?

Comment: @user384706 Yes. Once per connection. So you could only send one file.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Im confused about the n = dis.read(buf,0,Math.min) part, does the math.min determine if the file size is smaller than the buffer size? and if so, it will only partially fill the buffer with only the file.length?

Comment: @Tom The `Math.min()` is to handle the last buffer correctly. You can't assume the file size is a multiple of your buffer length.

Comment: @FadlyDzil This is not a coding service. I have already provided all the code necessary. I would expect any competent programmer to be able to turn my other remarks into working code.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this, it is working perfectly, you can take a look:

**Send**

```
byte[] done = new byte[3];
String str = "done";  //randomly anything
done = str.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(files.get(i).getName());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));
    while ((n = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
        dos.write(buf, 0, n);
        System.out.println(n);
        dos.flush();
    }
    //should i close the dataoutputstream here and make a new one each time?                 
    dos.write(done, 0, 3);
    dos.flush();
}
//or is this good?
dos.close();
```

**Receive**

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Receiving file: " + files.get(i).getName());
    //create a new fileoutputstream for each new file
    fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\users\\tom5\\desktop\\salestools\\" + files.get(i).getName());
    //read file
    while ((n = dis.read(buf)) != -1 && n != 3) {
        fos.write(buf, 0, n);
        fos.flush();
    }
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks to your problem, i learnt something new that what you were asking to close the `DataOutputStream` after every file transfer, it actually closes the underlying stream, and thus the socket is kind of closed. `Close()-Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.` Javadocs.

Comment: hmmm, I'm sending the file size now and storing them in a int array.  I added this to my server  while loop,     while((n = dis.read(buf)) != -1 && bytesRead < fileSize));

Comment: ok, i tried that too, but there was a loss/gain of few bytes. Just check the last file that was transferred, is it losing few bytes?

Comment: oh ya, for example, receiving 5 files, sometimes it will receive all the bytes in the first 3 iterations, and the 2 last files would be 0 bytes, sometimes it would receive bytes into the 4th iteration.  Was pretty random

Comment: Although, read the above post where Math.min was added to the while((n = dis.read(buf,0,Math.min(n, FileSizes[i])).  That corrected the problem completely, but scrambled my brain in the process

Comment: This can't work. It assumes the only time you get a read count of three is when you are sending the inter-file sentinel. It will fail if the file size is 3 modulo the buffer size, or any other time TCP chooses to deliver you three bytes, which it can do any time it likes. -1

Answer (score 0):

I have created a server and client. They are establishing connection and after that server is sending 1MB text file in every second. Server and client code is below. I have tested long duration and saw that there is no data lost. I have modified the above answered little bit.

SERVER CODE:

```
package com.dd.server;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        byte[] done = new byte[3];
        String str = "done";  //randomly anything
        done = str.getBytes();
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000); 
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[4096];
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
       
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        while(true) {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            File myFile= new File("I:\\MY-LEARNINGS\\JAVA\\Workspace\\server\\src\\com\\dd\\server\\gistfile1.txt");
            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());     
            dos.writeLong(myFile.length());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            int read;
            System.out.println("---------File Writing started----------");
            int count = 0;
            while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
                dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
                dos.flush();
                ++count;
                System.out.println("Writing sub component of file. Step : "+count);
            }
            System.out.println("---------File Writing ended----------");
            System.out.println("Flushing data DONE command sent.");
            dis.close();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("File transfer has been completed.");
            dos.write(done, 0, 3);
            dos.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
 package clientcom.dd.clent;

 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        while(true) {
            FileOutputStream fos = 
                    new FileOutputStream("I:\\MY-LEARNINGS\\JAVA\\Workspace\\client\\"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"-data.txt");
            int read = 0;
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1 && read != 3) {
                fos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
                fos.flush();
            }
            fos.close();
            //System.out.println("The value of read : "+read);
           // System.out.println("File has been received successfully.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```