# Sending/Receiving a file name before sending content through TCP/SSL socket

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp

I have the servers connected, but I don't really understand how TCP works well enough to accomplish the task. I want to send the file name before I starting writing the content, but how can I read the file name separately from the content. This was really easy in UDP with socket.receive(packet), but I can't think of a comparable way of doing this with TCP sockets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367698/java-multiple-file-transfer-over-socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, depending on the design of your protocol:

1. send the filename length as a fixed-sized integer, then send the actual filename.  The receiver can then read the length first and subsequently read however many bytes it indicates to read the filename.

   ```
   <length><filename><file data>
   ```
2. send the filename and then send a unique delimiter, such as a `CRLF`.  The receiver can then keep reading until it encounters the delimiter.

   ```
   <filename><delimiter><file data>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Write the length of the filename using a fixed number of bytes. Then write the filename.

On the receiving side, read the length of the filename and then once you know the length, read the filename.