# Java file transfer over RMI

Tags: java, rmi, file-transfer

What is the easiest way to transfer files over RMI ?

Answer (score 3):

RMI is a poor choice for this application. There is too much implicit data copying, and too much latency if you use multiple method calls.

Use a socket or an HTTP connection. See my answer in [this question](/questions/10367698/java-multiple-file-transfer-over-socket) for a general-purpose solution.

I don't know why you are so fixated on using RMI for this. You've posted half a dozen questions on it, and you've already been told several times, e.g. now-deleted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50666927/207421), that it isn't suitable, or part of an overload avoidance strategy as you claimed.